# another jsp not found

Tags: jsp, liferay

Making a super simple portlet. It has two jsp pages one tells it is first and has a button directing to second and vice versa.

Here is its primitive code:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="goURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/second.jsp" /> 
</portlet:renderURL>

<h2>First view</h2>
<aui:button type="submit" value="Go second" onClick="<%= goURL%>"/>
```

When I run it on local server after out of eclipse deployment - everything goes fine. But! When I make war-file and deploy it on remote server, after clicking this button "not found" and some wild address as if I were searching it at the whole portal displayed.

How it should be made for normal work on remote server?

Comment: May be some more information would help. Like version of Liferay, the error you get, the difference of environment between local and remote server and your portlet code (or are you just extending `MVCPortlet` of liferay)

Comment: In addition, your directory listing would be helpful for where second.jsp is located relative to the docroot.

Comment: SOLVED here [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/20672730)